# How to get plugin_dir_path of a directory in WordPress

Tags: file, path, directory, wordpress

I am using the Meta Box plugin from Delux Blog Tips (http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box/) and need to change the defined constants in the plugin. I need to do this because I am using the plugin inside a plugin and not a theme.

I have placed the plugin inside a folder called "`lib/meta-box`" which is inside my plugin directory.

Using the WordPress "`plugin_dir_path()`" function I need to define the path to the above folder.

I have tried this:

```
define('RWMB_DIR', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));
```

but this doesn't include the "`lib/meta-box`" directory.

The file defining the constant is located in the root of the plugin directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
$dir = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'lib/meta-box';
define('RWMB_DIR', $dir);
```